# knockout Data bind to ASP gridview

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, webforms

I have an ASP.Net gridview that i would like to data-bind to. What i would like to do is change the color of the row when a button on the row is clicked/row is selected. I would like to accomplish this using knockoutjs on the front end. Doing something very much like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/yTtFu/1/)** .
I havent found anything that would clarify how i would data-bind to a row and get the selected row to change.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grvAccounts" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" OnRowCommand="grvAccounts_RowCommand1" DataKeyNames="UDField1">
            <AlternatingRowStyle/>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
     />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EDF3FC" /> 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="80px" HeaderText="Process">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnProcess" Text="Process" runat="server" CommandName="Process" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UDField1" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide" />

 />

                <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountID" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MasterID" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="80px" HeaderText="Download">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" Text="Download" runat="server" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $("[id*=GridView1] td").bind("click", function () {
        var row = $(this).parent();
        $("[id*=GridView1] tr").each(function () {
            if ($(this)[0] != row[0]) {
                $("td", this).removeClass("selected_row");
            }
        });
        $("td", row).each(function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass("selected_row")) {
                $(this).addClass("selected_row");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("selected_row");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use this function with jQuery library for add colour in gridview client side and add css for class added in script and Mark this answer as right if it work for you

Comment: should it be id*=Gridview instead of Gridview1? Also then my css class would be .Selected_row{ background-color:#bfd8ff} correct?

Comment: is there a way to access that data in the selected row from JS?

Comment: yes there is a way please add new question in stack i will update you there